# jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy haciendo un sistema para un gimnasio. Estoy usando AJAX con JQuery. Estoy en la parte de creación de venta y cuando quiero guardar la venta y para que se guarde en la base de datos también me sale este error:

> jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Illegal invocation

el código donde creo yo que me esta dando error es este:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        if(vents.items.prod.length === 0){
            message_error('Debe al menos tener un item en su detalle de venta');
            return false;
        }

        vents.items.fecha_registro= $('input[name="fecha_registro"]').val();
        vents.items.cli= $('select[name="cli"]').val();
        var parameters = new FormData();
        parameters.append('action', $('input[name="action"]').val());
        parameters.append('vents', JSON.stringify(vents.items));
        submit_with_ajax(document.title, "", "info", window.location.pathname, parameters, function(){
            location.href = '/gym/dashboard/';
        });
    });
    vents.list();
});
```